# Invite new user to website per e-mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to build a form on my website where users, who are already registered, could invite new users via e-mail to sign up for this website. The user who sent the invitation and the user who accepted the invitation (and signed up) are then connected through a "friendship" relationship.

I would like to send the invitations via the ActionMailer.

My problem is: How do I "link" the email to the friendship-relationship. One way is probably to create a unique sender_id, which points to the user and which will be used as a link in the email.

Is there another possibility?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link create an argument, where you can pass an ID that could identify your relationship.
Something like: http://example.com/invite?abcd

Than in you controller you can treat the relationship.

Other option is to use [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)

Comment: Yeah, this was my plan too. Cheers for confirmation!